# Remote debugging on x64 Windows Server 2003

Tags: visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

I had a web service installed on an 32-bit Windows Server 2003 machine. I was able to remotely debug it from my Windows 7 64-bit machine with VS 2010, by making the x86 debugger exe available from a share on my machine. Everything was working fine until over the weekend they decided to upgrade the server machine to 64-bit.

Now when I try to remotely debug with the x86 debugger it gives me the error:

[image: Remote Debugger]

When I use the x64 debugger, it doesn't throw an error but it doesn't load the symbols for the project so I can't debug it anyway.

Any ideas as to why this is? What should I be doing differently?

Comment: `doesn't load the symbols for the project` <-- have you gone to the Modules window (under Debug menu) to look at the symbol load information for a particular assembly? what does it say?  Also, is the web service process running as 32 or 64bit?  As an experiment you could try (forcing) your process to run as 32bit to see if remote debugging works with that.

Comment: The Modules window doesn't even include the project assemblies. It just shows the system32 and GAC assemblies...I've tried running the process in both 32 and 64 bit, and I get the same problems.

Comment: when running process as 32 bit i'm assuming you get past the initial problem that you posted (the dialog one). btw, what actually happens after you attach to process? make sure you have the output window open and check your output settings (`Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Output Window`) - it may indicate where its falling over. I would guess the symbols for the version of the framework on that machine arent available on the symbol server.

Comment: Also its very strange to update a machine running 32bit 2003 windows to 64bit 2003 windows?? *checks current date on calendar* :)

Comment: Oh I know how strange it is for that update. Don't even why they had a need for it, but they did it, and I have to deal with it.  The output window doesn't display anything. :/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is an option for you but you can either

- set VS to produce an x86 executable (build options, platform target x86)
- or if your web service is running in IIS, create an app pool that runs as a x86 process

> Go to Application Pools in the IIS Management Console, right click your
>   application pool and select "Set Application Pool Defaults...". In the
>   properties dialog, set "Enable 32 Bit Applications" to "True."

That way your should be able to use the x86 debugger (since that worked before).

---

apparently you can set IIS 6 to run in x86 mode with:

```
%SystemDrive%\inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs set w3svc/AppPools/Enable32bitAppOnWin64 1
```

afterwards also run

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -i
```

Comment: I've built the service to target x86, but the "Enable 32 Bit Applications" setting seems to be in IIS7 and later. Windows Server 2003 uses IIS6. No joy unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

please ensure that you are doing the folowing

- -ensure you have the uptodate symbols with you executable on the server
- -run the 64 bit version of msvsmon.exe
- -on your client in visual studios, debug - attach to process - transport (remote) qualifier (your server)
- -select the process and hit attach

you must have the same version of the executable and symbols on server and client